# Fedora 27 new install doesn't bring login dialog

Tags: fedora, boot, systemd, dynamic-linking

I just installed the latest updates today 11/25/17 and getting to "F" icon during boot and nothing happens.

Logging in "single" mode, I get these messages:

```
FAILED to start Journal Serice
FAILED to start Apply Kernel Variables
/usr/bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-234.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and then nothing, can't execute any command - it hangs and is unresponsive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a version mismatch somehow. Do you by any chance have the updates-testing repository enabled? (if so, probably "don't do that" to leave things more stable) You may be able to use a Fedora live CD to perform repairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
# boot knoppix down to single user mode:
telinit 2
# Mount main partition from my computer's hard drive
mkdir /media/mycomputer
mount -t auto -o acl /dev/disk/by-uuid/blahblah...  /media/mycomputer
# Share some things from running system, to keep various applications
# and the kernel happy.
mount --bind /dev /media/mycomputer/dev
mount --bind /tmp /media/mycomputer/tmp
mount --bind /proc /media/mycomputer/proc
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf /media/mycomputer/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /media/mycomputer

# Now everything works:
/etc/init.d/kdm start
# (use gdm if you don't have kdm)
```

systemd-shared-234.so
 dnf install systemd-234-9.fc27.i686

```
[root@localhost /]# rpm -qf $(rpm -Va 2>&1 | grep -vE '^$|prelink:' | sed 's|.* /|/|') | sort -u
audit-2.8.2-1.fc27.x86_64
brlapi-0.6.6-8.fc27.x86_64
ca-certificates-2017.2.20-1.0.fc27.noarch
cronie-anacron-1.5.1-8.fc27.x86_64
cups-filters-1.16.1-3.fc27.x86_64
dnf-conf-2.7.5-2.fc27.noarch
fedora-logos-26.0.1-3.fc27.x86_64
fedora-release-27-1.noarch
filesystem-3.3-3.fc27.x86_64
fwupdate-efi-10-0.2.fc27.x86_64
gdm-3.26.2.1-3.fc27.x86_64
grub2-common-2.02-19.fc27.noarch
grub2-efi-ia32-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-efi-ia32-cdboot-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-efi-x64-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-efi-x64-cdboot-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-tools-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
iscsi-initiator-utils-6.2.0.874-6.git86e8892.fc27.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.151-1.b12.fc27.x86_64
kexec-tools-2.0.15-12.fc27.1.x86_64
libgpod-0.8.3-19.fc27.x86_64
mactel-boot-0.9-16.fc27.x86_64
memtest86+-5.01-16.fc26.x86_64
PackageKit-1.1.7-1.fc27.x86_64
pam-1.3.0-6.fc27.i686
pam-1.3.0-6.fc27.x86_64
plymouth-0.9.3-0.9.20160620git0e65b86c.fc27.x86_64
ppp-2.4.7-13.fc27.x86_64
psacct-6.6.2-7.fc27.x86_64
python3-colorama-0.3.7-6.fc27.noarch
python3-dnf-plugins-core-2.1.5-1.fc27.noarch
python3-six-1.11.0-1.fc27.noarch
R-core-3.4.3-1.fc27.x86_64
selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-283.19.fc27.noarch
setup-2.10.10-1.fc27.noarch
shim-ia32-13-0.7.x86_64
shim-x64-13-0.7.x86_64
source-highlight-3.1.8-14.fc27.x86_64
syslinux-extlinux-nonlinux-6.04-0.7.fc27.noarch
systemd-234-9.fc27.i686
systemd-234-9.fc27.x86_64
systemd-udev-234-9.fc27.x86_64
texlive-kpathsea-svn41139-36.fc27.5.noarch
texlive-tetex-svn41059-36.fc27.5.noarch
[root@localhost /]# [root@localhost /]# rpm -qf $(rpm -Va 2>&1 | grep -vE '^$|prelink:' | sed 's|.* /|/|') | sort -u
audit-2.8.2-1.fc27.x86_64
brlapi-0.6.6-8.fc27.x86_64
ca-certificates-2017.2.20-1.0.fc27.noarch
cronie-anacron-1.5.1-8.fc27.x86_64
cups-filters-1.16.1-3.fc27.x86_64
dnf-conf-2.7.5-2.fc27.noarch
fedora-logos-26.0.1-3.fc27.x86_64
fedora-release-27-1.noarch
filesystem-3.3-3.fc27.x86_64
fwupdate-efi-10-0.2.fc27.x86_64
gdm-3.26.2.1-3.fc27.x86_64
grub2-common-2.02-19.fc27.noarch
grub2-efi-ia32-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-efi-ia32-cdboot-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-efi-x64-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-efi-x64-cdboot-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
grub2-tools-2.02-19.fc27.x86_64
iscsi-initiator-utils-6.2.0.874-6.git86e8892.fc27.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.151-1.b12.fc27.x86_64
kexec-tools-2.0.15-12.fc27.1.x86_64
libgpod-0.8.3-19.fc27.x86_64
mactel-boot-0.9-16.fc27.x86_64
memtest86+-5.01-16.fc26.x86_64
PackageKit-1.1.7-1.fc27.x86_64
pam-1.3.0-6.fc27.i686
pam-1.3.0-6.fc27.x86_64
plymouth-0.9.3-0.9.20160620git0e65b86c.fc27.x86_64
ppp-2.4.7-13.fc27.x86_64
psacct-6.6.2-7.fc27.x86_64
python3-colorama-0.3.7-6.fc27.noarch
python3-dnf-plugins-core-2.1.5-1.fc27.noarch
python3-six-1.11.0-1.fc27.noarch
R-core-3.4.3-1.fc27.x86_64
selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-283.19.fc27.noarch
setup-2.10.10-1.fc27.noarch
shim-ia32-13-0.7.x86_64
shim-x64-13-0.7.x86_64
source-highlight-3.1.8-14.fc27.x86_64
syslinux-extlinux-nonlinux-6.04-0.7.fc27.noarch
systemd-234-9.fc27.i686
systemd-234-9.fc27.x86_64
systemd-udev-234-9.fc27.x86_64
texlive-kpathsea-svn41139-36.fc27.5.noarch
texlive-tetex-svn41059-36.fc27.5.noarch
[root@localhost /]#
```

https://nmilosev.svbtle.com/dbus-woes-with-fedora-in-a-chroot